# How to solve "implode(): Invalid arguments passed"?

Tags: php, html, implode

I'm trying to implode some checkbox values into a single String to store it on a Database field (as it is the only way I think I can do it), but I'm getting this error:

```
implode(): Invalid arguments passed
```

My HTML code is:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="oportunitats[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="oportunitats[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="oportunitats[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="oportunitats[]" value="4">
```

And my PHP looks like this:

```html
$chk_oportunitats = implode(",",$_POST["oportunitats"]);
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? Have you checked what `,$_POST["oportunitats"]` contains in case of that error?

Comment: @NicoHaase I realized it shows the error when the array is empty, when I first load the form. Once I select some checkboxes and submit again, it disappears.

Comment: If you've solved it, you should post an answer and accept it to help future visitors.  Great job!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was I was checking $chk_oportunitats before any checkbox was selected, so the array was empty.

Solution PHP looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST["oportunitats"])){
        $chk_oportunitats = implode(",",$_POST["oportunitats"]);
      }
```